# jQuery glDatePicker Changing selectedDate after the calendar has rendered?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I cannot seem to be able to change "selectedDate" after the calendar has rendered. Reference guide says it is possible to change calendar's options after it has rendered and it holds true for values like cssName and borderSize and selectableDateRange, but modifying "selectedDate" does not seem to have any effect? Is this intended or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi sbay, Did you find your solutions yet?? i am facing same problems here.

Comment: Facing the same problem .. Any help pls ?

Answer (score 1):

The selected date is updated, only you also have to update the first date of the displayed calendar.

Suppose your calendar is *already attached* to `#something`:

```
// get reference
var dp = $('#something').glDatePicker(true);

// update selected date
dp.selectedDate = new Date(2013, 9, 8);

// update first date
dp.firstDate = new Date(2013, 9, 1);

// render
dp.render();
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the current solution works, to reset selectedDate and firstDate need to to do:

```
dp.options.selectedDate = new Date()
```

And the render call fails with undefined returned.

Answer (score 0):

@eepp solution works with following change...

REPLACE following code:

```
// update first date
dp.firstDate = new Date(2013, 9, 1);
```

WITH:

```
// update first date
dp.options.firstDate = new Date(2013, 9, 1);
```